# My PostgreSQL 9.5 DB is too slow

Tags: database, postgresql

Database Server

- OS: Ubuntu 14.04
- RAM: 16G
- HDD: 200G

Until last month, I used PostgreSQL 9.3. It's very good performance. then I should change PostgreSQL 9.5.4. After change, Database is too slow.

1) I exported data from PostgreSQL 9.3 with this command:

```
pg_dump -U postgres --format=c -d <dbname> -f backup.dump
```

2) I installed PostgreSQL 9.5.4. I import backup.dump with this two commands:

```
pg_restore -j 5 -v -d <dbname> -U postgres --schema-only backup.dump

pg_restore -j 5 -v -d <dbname> -U postgres --disable-triggers --data-only backup.dump
```

Both dump and restore processes are completed successfully.
But performance is poor.

Am I missing options in above process?

Or where should I start check for improving Database speed?

Comment: Slow when doing what?

Comment: Have you `vacuum analyze`-d your database? Is `autovacuum` enabled?

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: I tried vacuumdb --full and autovacuum enabled. same situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the problem is truly "database wide" then:
 1. You haven't analyzed your data (Statistics are off)
 2. You migrated to slower disks than before.
 3. You Postgres.cfg file might have worse settings than before.

You should also look at whether your memory is fully used (via top or some other tool). Look at CPU usage and disk I/O as well.

If possible, you should see if this problem occurs only under production level load, or if it'll behave "slowly" with 1 user using your application.

Using this info, will help a ton. For example, if memory is  TOO HIGH (Massive swap usage), the problem may be in your config. The problem is also in your config if memory is NOT being utilized much-- you want your DB to use as much memory as is feasible within your work load (it's complicated though because some memory is shared among the whole DB, other is based on how many active connections you have simultaneously)

If it's an I/O issue, then you could have moved to a slower disk-- or you could have index or even optimizer issues (IE, certain optimizer options might be disabled)

Please reply with your CPU, DISK I/O, SWAP, and memory usages.. preferably "under some kind of load" so we can see what resource or resources are under contention.